# Css files treated as html files after merge

Tags: html, css, jsp, jakarta-ee

I had two branches on github. The second one was for the front integration and worked perfectly untill I merged it with the master.

My **index.jsp** file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="ex" uri="/WEB-INF/custom.tld" %>

<html>
<jsp:include page="pages/headFragment.jsp"/>

<body>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

The **headFragment.jsp** is:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<head>
<!-- Animate.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/animate.css">
    <!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/icomoon.css">
    <!-- Simple Line Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/simple-line-icons.css">
</head>
```

In a browser's console I have few errors:
    ***SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'***
but they are connected with css files which are not css files. My animate.css is interpreted by the browser as the html file with the body of whole page. The links are interpreted normally, but theirs' body isn't.

I think that's the problem with linking the css stylesheets, but I googled and tried a lot of options and nothing worked. The interesting part is that on a front-integration part it is normally working, but after merge it does not include css files. There's also problem with js files, but I tried to repare css firstly...

And, by the way, I work on Intellij 2016.2.4

Also my **pom.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>webpage</groupId>
    <artifactId>web_page</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>web</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://repo1.maven.org/maven -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whom it may concern.

The problem occured bacause of the global welcome path '/' to the loaded servlet. Change of this path to f.e. '/yolo' resolves all of the conflicts.